# JSON in Trigger Function

Tags: postgresql

I use this extension [pg_net](https://github.com/supabase/pg_net) to call external apis.
The trigger that I have created is below:

```
begin 
perform   
net.http_post(         
url:='https://httpbin.org/post',   
body:='{"msg": "'+NEW.message+'" ,"hello": "world"}'::jsonb     
) as request_id;  
RETURN NULL; 
end;
```

If I run the trigger I get this error

> "No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. operator does not exist: unknown + text"

If I run it without the NEW.message (which I want) I don't get any error.

Any idea?

Comment: In PostgreSQL `+` is arithmetic-only operator, it does not concatenate strings (rather than MS SQL). Use `||` operator or CONCAT/CONCAT_WS function - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html

Comment: @Akina I tried with->  body:='{"msg": "'||NEW.message||'" ,"hello": "world"}'::jsonb  and I get -> "Token "hello" is invalid."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jsonb_build_object()` it will automatically take care of any embedded quotes in the value so you don't have to escape them manually.

```
begin 
perform   
net.http_post(         
  url := 'https://httpbin.org/post',   
  body := jsonb_build_object('msg', NEW.message, 'hello', 'world')
  ) as request_id;  
RETURN NULL; 
end;
```

Note that using `:=` for named parameters is deprecated in favor of the standard compliant `=>`

Comment: I get -> { msg: null, hello: 'world' }

Comment: Then `NEW.message` contains no value

Comment: Yes it works! I had to set my trigger to fire for processed row not statement. Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is, but it's `null`.

Comment: How can I select data from other table before I perform the request?  I tried with username := select username from users where user_id = new.message_sentby but I get error